# Pagespeed-penalty for using srcset

Tags: css, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, srcset

Displaying retina & non-retina to corresponding devices like this:

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="non-retina.jpg, retina.jpg 2x">
   <img src="non-retina.jpg">
</picture>
```

Works. But Google Pagespeed Insight is telling that it cannot render this until the CSS is loaded, and we get a penalty for it. Only in mobile-view, however - which is the only case where Pagespeed Insights is rendering Retina-images anyway.

Our complete CSS-file is in the footer, as we have the above-the-fold, critical CSS inline in the head.

This code, however, works without any complaints from Pagespeed Insights

```
<picture>
  <img src="non-retina.jpg">
</picture>
```

What are we missing? Is there some dependency that the browser has to read the style-rules before knowing which source/srcset-image to take?

**Testcase:**

Here's a test page for it: http://pagespeed-srcset-nopicturefill.slople.com/
...
and here's its results: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpagespeed-srcset-nopicturefill.slople.com%2F&tab=mobile

Comment: are you using a polyfill to support the picture tag in older browser?

Comment: No. The same happens when just doing <img src="non-retina.jpg" srcset="non-retina.jpg, retina.jpg 2x">

Comment: according to https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/#support seems like some browser, which doesn't fully support the picture/srcset spec, have some issue with http requests. I don't know if this issue affects the pagespeed results too, though

Comment: also, I use the picture/srcset on a number of production-ready ecommerce and I don't see any complain about it by pagespeed: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.gioiapura.it (pagespeed complains about other issues). I use the picturefill polyfill I mentioned above, now I'm on a smartphone and I can't do any test to check if it matters or not

Comment: look again, pagespeed is complaining about render-blocking css/js on your page. We do not have that on our page (100/100 score) if we remove the srcset.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out,  I'll take a deeper look at it as soon as I can. Your question raise an interesting point, since the blocking scripts that pagespeed list aren't directly involved in the picture rendering I never realized that it could have an impact on performance.

Comment: I get 100/100 mobile score with the same markup as in your example and a CSS file loaded in the footer:  
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmadeyourday.net%2Fpagespeed-test-1  
Can you provide a link to the affected webpage, or a reduced test case that shows the pagespeed issue?

Comment: Any updates on this? Getting the same penalty.

Comment: @ausi our affected page is www.desirio.com ... sometimes we have it, sometimes not

Comment: You are not missing anything; Pagespeed incorrectly assumes your images can be optimized by comparing the dimensions of the rendered image to the file resolution. I wouldn't recommend focusing on the score itself, but rather on the actual metrics: critical rendering path, time to interactive, and tests on slow connections and low-end devices, does meaningful paint happen within first 3 seconds on 3G? Is there FOIT? 


Pagespeed score shouldn't affect your search results in any significant way either, so I wouldn't consider it penalizing.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Add Your css in Header and use defer attribute in link tag. This will allow css to be downloaded on client side first but read after the whole document is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this may not address the original question as it was posted by in 2016

**TL;DR:** Pay attention to the Lighthouse version which is typically listed at the end of the report! Depending on which tool you use to measure your performance scores, you results may vary and by a lot!

Apparently, Google Lighthouse algorithm differs between versions *quite a lot*. For instance, as of writing, 19 May 2021, I have written a website and run different tests on it to see the Lighthouse performance score. Here's the table for your comparison:

| device | 7.2.0 | 7.3.0 | 7.5.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| desktop | 94 | 94 | 95 |
| mobile | 92 | 72 | 95 |

To keep things simple:

- I am showing *only* performance score (that's your big overall value)
- I have run tests 3 times and averaged it to account for minor fluctuations

At the time of writing:

- Lighthouse `7.2.0` was shipped on MacOS Google Chrome
- Lighthouse `7.3.0` is used by PageSpeed Insights
- Lighthouse `7.5.0` is going to be shipped [within 2 weeks](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/releases/tag/v7.5.0) on PageSpeed Insights *and* Google Chrome 92

Answer (score -2):

I’m not sure if this will fix your problem, but this:

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="non-retina.jpg, retina.jpg 2x">
   <img src="non-retina.jpg">
</picture>
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
<img src="non-retina.jpg" srcset="retina.jpg 2x">
```

Maybe this helps?

Comment: I do not believe that is actually equivalent.

Comment: Why not? It seems to me both should display the non-retina version in low dpi environment and in browsers that don't support `picture` or `srcset`, and the retina version in high-dpi environment with compatible browsers.

Comment: Not is equivalent, <picture> generates a fallback image and <img src srcset> not